# Is it possible to look for last change of a property using envers

Tags: hibernate, audit

I am very new to Envers, I can see how to get the list of revisions for a certain entity, but is it possible to search for changes of a particular property?

I would like to find the previous version of the "name" property for my entity.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate may not support this functionality. You can try adding AUDIT TRIAL functionality using database triggers or same can be achieved using Hibernate events also..but the data needs to be stored in a seperate table.

Comment: This is not native hibernate functionality, envers provides auditing on top of hibernate.  I'm pretty sure it should be possible